# Calling Azure AD's enterprise aws single account access application using Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I have configured AWS single account access Enterprise application from Azure AD gallery and added Azure AD as identity provider in AWS side.
I am able to test the enterprise application from https://portal.azure.com/ and SSO is happening properly to AWS.

I want to perform the same thing using java, so that I can get authenticated to Azure AD and should able to retrieve the SAML assertion which can be later used for further actions.

So I am stuck at point of getting authenticated programmatically. Help would be appreciated

Comment: @Stefan Rasmusson : could you please help in this regard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.